# Multiple conditions on the same column in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table something like this -

```
RecordID   PropertyID       PropertyVal
--------------------------------------------------
3215            7           john doe
3215            11          Chicago
3215            13          Business Development Analyst
3216            7           jane doe
3216            11          Chicago
3216            13          Managing Director
3217            7           mike smith
3217            11          Chicago
3217            13          Business Development Analyst
3218            7           john smith
3218            11          Seattle
3218            13          Managing Director
```

How do I return the names of users where `PropertyID = 13 AND PropertyVal='Business Development Analyst'AND PropertyID = 11 AND PropertyVal = 'Chicago'`. How do I do multiple where clauses for the same column?

Edit:
I need the result set to look like this -

```
Name
----
John Doe
Mike Smith
```

Comment: This is an extremely bad database design. It will never be performant and there is no way to enforce data integrity.  Do not use an EAV table for properties that can be figured out at design time. (you also would not want to store the full name instead of the parts of the name because it makes finding people by last name much harder and much slower. This design will not scale and if you truly have no idea of the fields you will want (not name, city and job title), then at least use a nosql database that is designed for unstructured data. Redesign now before it is too late.

Comment: @HLGEM: This is a SharePoint out of the box table for the Profile service. I'm no database expert, but why would Microsoft use this approach if it's bad design?

Comment: Because it is faster and easier for the developers who don't have to live with the results of the drek they design. If they don't waste time thinking about the datbase design, then they get done faster. Developers who don't know about and practice good database design should not be allowed to design databases whether they work for Microsoft or not. Ask anyone who has supported sharepoint about whether they think it is well-designed product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select PropertyVal
from your_table
where PropertyID = 7
and RecordID in 
(
  select RecordID   
  from your_table
  where (PropertyID = 13 AND PropertyVal='Business Development Analyst')
     or (PropertyID = 11 AND PropertyVal = 'Chicago')
  group by RecordID   
  having count(distinct PropertyID) = 2
)
```

Comment: @Bohemian I just checked the MySQL documentation, and it says AND has higher precedence than OR, so I think he got it right. But I personally don't like to depend on it, and I always parenthesize expressions like this.

Comment: @Bohemian: I think it is correct. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: I can't see an error in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53882/1). And I googled it reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx) `When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, NOT is evaluated first, then AND, and finally OR. `

Comment: @juergend I don't know what I was thinking. It *is* correct (un -1). Sorry about that. Actually, I do know - I automatically use brackets whenever I use `OR`. It's only because these are the only conditions that this works. If you adding something else, you'd (probably) need brackets.

Comment: Works great! There is a typo in your code though. `PropertyVal=7` should actually be `PropertyID=7`.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you want exactly. It's probably either

```
...
where (PropertyID = 13 AND PropertyVal = 'Business Development Analyst')
   or (PropertyID = 11 AND PropertyVal = 'Chicago')
```

or

```
...
where PropertyID in (13, 11) 
and PropertyVal in ('Business Development Analyst', 'Chicago')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The resultset need to have only the names (propertyId = 7), but the where clause needs 13 & 11. Is that even possible?

Comment: I've updated the question with the resultset I'm looking for.

Comment: this should be the one considered the correct answer. Thanks! +1 for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

We can go with JOIN Clause...

Ex:

```
 SELECT LIST_OF_COLUMNS FROM TBL1 T1 JOIN TBL2 T2
    ON T1.COL1=T2.COL1 AND 
    T1.COL2=T2.COL2 AND 
    T1.COL3=T2.COL3 AND 
    T1.COL4=T2.COL4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LIST_OF_COLUMNS FROM TBL1 T1 JOIN TBL2 T2
    ON T1.COL1=T2.COL1 AND 
    T1.COL2=T2.COL2 AND 
    T1.COL3=T2.COL3 AND 
    T1.COL4=T2.COL4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using INTERSECT operator

```
select PropertyVal as "Name"
from mytable
where PropertyID=7
and RecordID in 
(
    select RecordID
    from mytable
    where PropertyID = 13 AND PropertyVal='Business Development Analyst'

    intersect

    select RecordID
    from mytable
    where PropertyID = 11 AND PropertyVal='Chicago'

)
```